Get the same not null value for all the records in a window
I want to get the same first/last not null value for all the records in a same window. I've prepared this example data:
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, NULL AS value, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS update_ts

  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 1, "Good", TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 1, "Bad", TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
)

SELECT
  id,
  value,
  FIRST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ids) AS first_valid_value,
  LAST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ids) AS last_valid_value,
  update_ts
FROM sample_data
WINDOW ids AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY update_ts DESC)

This is the output for this query:



id
value
first_valid_value
last_valid_value
update_ts




1



2024-12-13 12:37:05.762489 UTC


1
Good
Good
Good
2024-12-12 12:37:05.762489 UTC


1
Bad
Good
Bad
2024-12-11 12:37:05.762489 UTC



There are two things which are confusing me:

I added the INGORE NULLS part because I want to get a "valid" value, so I was expecting the first row (with NULL value field), to inherit the "Good" value in the first_valid_value field, and "Bad" for last_valid_value
In row #2, I was surprised that field last_valid_value didn't inherited the "Bad" value, as the window function is defining

This is the output I want to achieve and which I was expecting:



id
value
first_valid_value
last_valid_value
update_ts




1

Good
Bad
2024-12-13 12:37:05.762489 UTC


1
Good
Good
Bad
2024-12-12 12:37:05.762489 UTC


1
Bad
Good
Bad
2024-12-11 12:37:05.762489 UTC



Why is this happening, and how could I achieve the final result?

You need to specify the window frame clause:
SELECT
  id,
  value,
  FIRST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ids) AS first_valid_value,
  LAST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ids) AS last_valid_value,
  update_ts
FROM sample_data
WINDOW ids AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY update_ts DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)

Output:

From the docs:

For aggregate analytic functions, if the ORDER BY clause is present but the window frame clause is not, the following window frame clause is used by default:
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW


I read the documentation on the window frame clause, but I couldn't relate how this managed to solve the issue. Could you please explain but was being evaluated before you added that piece of logic, and what happened after you added it? Sorry, this is my first time facing a frame clause in a window function, but I think this will really help me level up so I want to understand it

Without specifying the window frame clause, the FIRST_VALUE will use ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#def_window_spec
